# POST is not working in my hosting service

Tags: php

I have this code for getting username and password:

```
<form action="checklogin.php" method="post">
                <table>
                    <TR><TD>Username: </TD><TD> <input type="text" name="username" required="required" class="ipt"/> </TD></TR>
                    <TR><TD>Password: </TD><TD> <input type="password" name="password" required="required" class="ipt" /> </TD></TR>
                    <TR><TD></TD><TD ><input type="submit" value="Login"/> </TD></TR>
                </table>
            </form>
```

its working correctly in local machine using XAMP. But when I transferred the files to my real severer,  checklogin.php can not receive username and I checked $username is empty in checklogin.php:

```
    //in checklogin.php:
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL); 
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    session_start();
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    mysql_connect("localhost", "xxxxxx","xxxxxxx") or die(mysql_error()); //Connect to server
    mysql_select_db("xxxxxxx") or die("Cannot connect to database"); //Connect to database
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * from users WHERE username='$username'"); //Query the users table if there are matching rows equal to $username


    $exists = mysql_num_rows($query); //Checks if username exists

    $table_users = "";
    $table_password = "";
    if($exists > 0) //IF there are no returning rows or no existing username
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) //display all rows from query
        {
            $table_users = $row['username']; // the first username row is passed on to $table_users, and so on until the query is finished
            $table_password = $row['password']; // the first password row is passed on to $table_users, and so on until the query is finished
        }
        if(($username == $table_users) && ($password == $table_password)) // checks if there are any matching fields
        {
                if($password == $table_password)
                {
                    $_SESSION['user'] = $username; //set the username in a session. This serves as a global variable
                    header("location: home.php"); // redirects the user to the authenticated home page
                }

        }
        else
        {
            Print '<script>alert("Incorrect Password!");</script>'; //Prompts the user
            Print '<script>window.location.assign("login.php");</script>'; // redirects to login.php
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Print '<script>alert("Incorrect Username!");</script>'; //Prompts the user
        Print '<script>window.location.assign("login.php");</script>'; // redirects to login.php
    }
?>
```

I checked connection to database is OK.
How can I trace the problem

I got this warnings after adding some reporting codes:
[image]

Comment: View source in the browser. I'm sure you'll see your javascript that you're printing. Maybe you'll even notice the syntax error.

Comment: your `Print '<script>alert(' . $username . ');</script>';` will result in a javascript syntax error, as your `$username` needs to be quoted as it is a string - `Print '<script>alert("' . $username . '");</script>';`

Comment: *" checked connection to database is OK."* - which is.. `mysql_`? -  `mysqli_`? - PDO?

Comment: plus, is the HTML form and PHP/SQL inside the same file?

Comment: `echo $username;` what does that say?

Comment: That Print '<script>alert...  show an empty box and no error message. It is with mysql_. and HTML form  and PHP/SQL are in same file.

Comment: double jeopardy then

Comment: btw, id's are supposed to be unique `id="ipt"` - use "class".

Comment: echo $username shows nothing.

Comment: I changed id to class. thanks Fred good notice.

Comment: You're welcome. Try adding error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: I have used or die(mysql_error()). I will test error reporting code and get back to post.

Comment: error reporting was good idea. please check the result in image I have added to post. I don't know any thing about 'root'! username is 'admin'.

Comment: Given the errors and what you said *"I checked connection to database is OK."* - that doesn't say that you've successfully connected. Post your connection codes and replace credentials with `xxx`.

Comment: I put whole the code in main post.

Comment: my guess is that you first need to connect, then pass DB connection to `mysql_real_escape_string()` or just use `mysqli_` for everything, or PDO. I won't be able to help any further, but that's my *educated* guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I outlined in comments:

> *"my guess is that you first need to connect, then pass DB connection to mysql_real_escape_string() or just use mysqli_ for everything, or PDO."*

So by the looks of your error messages, your server's setup most likely requires DB connection be passed as a parameter:

Pass the DB connection to your function(s) and modifying your present connection codes to:

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "xxxxxx","xxxxxxx");
mysql_select_db("xxxxxxx", $conn) or die(mysql_error($conn));
```

Example from the manual:

```
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$conn) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}
```

then:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'], $conn);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password'], $conn);
```

However, this would work out better using `mysqli_` or PDO and using prepared statements, since `mysql_` functions are deprecated and will be removed from future PHP releases.

Make sure also that your HTML form is not above your PHP, since you may be outputting before headers. Place your `<?php session_start(); ?>` first, then the rest of your PHP, then your HTML, or use two seperate files.

Plus, you mention that you are using both your HTML form and PHP/MySQL inside the same file.

You need to use a conditional `!empty()` for your inputs.

[**Use `mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

Reference(s):

- MySQLi connection: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

---

Footnotes:

Add `exit;` after each header. Otherwise, your code may want to continue to execute.

I.e.:

```
header("location: home.php");
exit;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked perfect.

Comment: @Alireza you are most welcome.